# Question about with Radiobutton using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Cake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window=Tk()
        
        self.window.title("Type of Cake")
        # self.window.geometry("500x300")    #window size


        
        self.choice =IntVar()
        self.velvet_radiobutton= Radiobutton(self.window, text="Red Velvet Cake", var=self.choice, value=0)
        self.velvet_radiobutton.grid(row=0, column=0)
       
        
        self.chocolate_radiobutton= Radiobutton(self.window, text="Chocolate Cake", var=self.choice, value=1 )
        self.chocolate_radiobutton.grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        self.carrot_radiobutton= Radiobutton(self.window, text="Carrot Cake", var=self.choice, value=2 )
        self.carrot_radiobutton.grid(row=2, column=0)
        
        
        self.submit_button=Button(self.window, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0)
      
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def submit(self):
        print(self.choice.get())
        if self.choice.get()==2:
            velvet_cake =Velvet_cake()
            print(self.choice.get())
        else:
            print("dont work")
            
    
def submit1():
    #entry.get() will give you a string
    shape=shape_entry.get()
    topping= topping_entry.get()
    name=name_entry.get()
    
    #name validation    
    if not name.isalpha():
        print("Please input an appropriate name")
        return
    
    if not shape.isalpha():
        print("Please input an appropriate cake shape")
        return
    
    if topping.isdecimal():
        topping= int(topping)
    else:
        print("This is not a valid number")
        return
    
    #compare age
    if topping>50:
        print("That's too many toppings!")
    elif topping<0:
        print("Topping number is invalid")
    else:
        print(f"Hi {name}, you've ordered {topping} toppings on a {shape} cake. That sounds delicious!")
        Zoo=Cake()


class Velvet_cake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window= Tk()
        self.window.title("Receipt")
        

main= Tk()
main.title("Online Cake Order")


# image_file= Image.open("CakeBran.png")
# image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_file)
# image_label=Label(main, image=image)
# image_label.grid(row=0,columnspan=3)

name_label = Label(main, text= "Name")
name_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

name_entry = Entry(main)
name_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

shape_label = Label(main, text="Shape of Cake")
shape_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

shape_entry = Entry(main)
shape_entry.grid(row=2,column=1)

topping_label =Label(main, text="Number of topings")
topping_label.grid(row=3,column=0)

topping_entry= Entry(main)
topping_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

submit_button=Button(main, text="Submit",command=submit1)
submit_button.grid(row=4, column=2)


main.mainloop()
```

Basically, my question is inside the Cake Class. When I run the code and  choose an option in the the second window, it doesn't open a third window named "Receipt" which I don't understand why?

When I Choose the third option "Carrot Cake" and submit, it should print `self.choice.get()` the enter the if statement of the submit function but it doesn't, it automatically goes to the else statement[This is the output I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8nbb.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For child windows, use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have used multiple instances of `Tk()`.  For child windows, use `Toplevel()` instead:

```py
class Cake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Toplevel()  # use Toplevel() instead of Tk()
        ...

...

class Velvet_cake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Toplevel()  # use Toplevel() instead of Tk()
        self.window.title("Receipt")

...
```